# Even after filling the right credentials the validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have started learning Javascript and DOM today and I am kinda stuck with this issue right now. Please go through the following lines of code and help me figure out where I am going wrong. I am somehow landing up in the else block no matter what I type in the input field.

```js
var user1 = {
    username: "Amit",
    password: "123321",
};

var user2 = {
    username: "Amir",
    password: "123456",
};

var database = [user1, user2];

var user = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
var i; var button = document.getElementById("btn");

function isUserValid(user, pwd) {
    for(i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
        if (user == database[i].username && pwd == database[i].password)
            return i;
    }
    return false;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(user, pwd) {
    if (isUserValid(user, pwd))
        alert("Welcome " + database[i].username);
    else
        alert("Oops! wrong credentials");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    Username: <input id="user_name"> <br>
    Password: <input id="password" type="password"> <br>
    <button id="btn">Log In</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: these variables seem incorrect: `if (usr == database[i].username && pas == database[i].password)`  for 'usr' shouldnt that be "user" and pas be "pwd"? your passing in user and pwd so it looks like your issue is related to those var names in your loop?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo. I am using "user" and "pwd" only.

Comment: You don't have to modify your question since people is answering you or this will invalidate all answers...

Comment: @SibasishMohanty-Check my Answer.Hope it will help you

Comment: return true in the if block along with the following suggested changes helped solve this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @SibasishMohanty-please tell me if the function name is **isValidUser** so why is fail case it should return **true** value and also in event listener  how you are getting value of i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your javascript code like this:

```
var user1 = {
    username: "Amit",
    password: "123321",
};

var user2 = {
    username: "Amir",
    password: "123456",
};

var database = [user1, user2];

var button = document.getElementById("btn");

function isUserValid(user, pwd){
    var result = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < database.length; i++){
        if(user == database[i].username && pwd == database[i].password){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var user = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (isUserValid(user, pwd))
        alert("Welcome " + user);
    else
        alert("Oops! wrong credentials");
})
```

When you're getting `user` and `pwd` in global scope, it just init one time when browser evaluate codes first time.
By moving those variables receive to `button` click event you'll get them every time that event triggered.

**Edit:**
Also function that you provided here has wrong arguments.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(user, pwd) {
```

You can't get `user` and `pwd` from listener. It will give you `event` of that trigger.
You can check about it here: [HTML DOM addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

> When the event occurs, an event object is passed to the function as
>   the first parameter. The type of the event object depends on the
>   specified event. For example, the "click" event belongs to the
>   MouseEvent object.